# How to access values dynamically in other cells via indirect function in outlook

Tags: excel

I was thinking of making something like a random unique number generator, obvious the following method doesn't work very well for large quantities, but here i go:

```
A1=RANDBETWEEN(1,7+1-ROW()) -> dragged on column down to A7 generates numbers decrementally so as to use these for "the rest of the array"
C1=1;D1=2;E1=3;...;I1=7 -> these are the original numbers to be used
K1=if(a1=1,c1,if(a1=2,d1,...)) -> number at position a1 in the array 

A2=RANDBETWEEN(1,7+1-ROW()) -> just drag a1 down, represents the position of the 2nd unique random number from the array
C2=IF($A1<=COLUMN()-2,D1,C1) -> the new array will skip c1 if it was picked, otherwise use C1; D2,E2,...,I1 are dragged and will perform the same operation
K2=if(a2=1,c2,if(a2=2,d2,...)) -> number at position a2 in the new array (old number from line1 was removed)

from here on out everything is dragged down, until row 7 (because there are 7 unique numbers in the array,please ignore the zeroes created b=in positions I2,H3,I3,... (because they are not assigned anything because those numbers were removed)
```

Other than the fact of improving this inefficient formula by not using a whole sheet, especially when working with thousands of cells(memory problem).Is there a way of optimizing the K1=if(a1=1,c1,if(a1=2,d1,...)) part by using the indirect function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one can use

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

.just replace row(), and column() with numbers, in your case:

```
A1=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),A1+2))
```

should give you the value from C1 (current row, and value of a1+2, ie a1=1 -> a1+2 =3 which equates to column c), then just drag downwards and A2,A3,...,A7 will give the correct result

Another method is to use

```
=INDIRECT("C"&A1)
```

but since you use columns and not rows